# Linq to Entities filtering out default parameters

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities, .net-4.5

Say I have the below method where the insuredNumber is required to be populated but the remaining three parameters may contain default values as below

*Method Signature:*

```
public List<Portal_SurveyRecommendations> LoadSurveyRecommendations(string insuredNumber, string surveyLocationNumber, DateTime dateIssuedFilter, DateTime dateCompletedFilter)
{
}
```

*Defaults:*

```
surveyLocationNumber = "-1"
dateIssuedFilter = DateTime.MinValue
dateCompletedFilter = DateTime.MinValue
```

How do I then go about ignoring these default values in the resultant Linq to Entites query? I have tried the below but more results than expected are returned as the dates are not filtering correctly.

*Query:*

```
var surveys = ctx.Portal_SurveyRecommendations.
                Where(c => c.CustNum.Equals(insuredNumber)).
                Where(l => l.LocationKey.ToString().Equals(surveyLocationNumber)).
                Where(di => di.DateRecIssued.Value > dateIssuedFilter || di.DateRecIssued.Value == null).
                Where(dc => dc.DateRecComplete.Value > dateCompletedFilter || dc.DateRecComplete.Value == null).
                OrderBy(o => o.ReportKey).ThenBy(o => o.RecNumKey).ToList();
```

I suppose I could break down the query into sub query's, checking for default values but I am interested to see if this can be done in one statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to break it down:

```
var query = ctx.Portal_SurveyRecommendations
    .Where(c => c.CustNum == insuredNumber);
if(surveyLocationNumber != -1)
    query = query.Where(l => l.LocationKey == surveyLocationNumber);
if(dateIssuedFilter != DateTime.MinValue)
    query = query.Where(di => di.DateRecIssued == null
                           || di.DateRecIssued.Value > dateIssuedFilter);
if(dateCompletedFilter != DateTime.MinValue)
    query = query.Where(dc => dc.DateRecComplete == null
                           || dc.DateRecComplete.Value > dateCompletedFilter);
var surveys = query.OrderBy(o => o.ReportKey).ThenBy(o => o.RecNumKey).ToList();
```

Comment: Thought as much. Thanks Marc.